# how can i find alternating 1 and 0 using REGEX

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

the question is find all bit sequences which are alternating between 1 and 0, i.e., those that do not have more than 1 or 0 in a row and return it in a list.

what i did so far

```
  public static List<String> findBits(String text) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([01])(?!\\1)([01])(?:\\1\\2)*\\1?|(?<!\\S)[01](?!\\S)|1.|0.", Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    return matcher.results()
        .map(String::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

it should return

no binary numbers here 3434. -> [] **Empty List**

Hey friend this is a 1. -> **[1]**

Those are 1001, 1010, 1011, 1100, 1101 -> **[1010]**

This is a long value 1010101010 and this one as well 1010101010101011 -> **[1010101010]**

0 + 0 is a also a 0. -> **[0,0,0]**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```java
\b(?!\d*(\d)\1)[10]+\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jcTnuN/1/).

In Java, declare it with `"\\b(?!\\d*(\\d)\\1)[10]+\\b"`.

*Details*

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!\d*(\d)\1)` - no repeated subsequent digits allowed in the current number
- `[10]+` - one or more `1` or `0` chars
- `\b` - a word boundary

See a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/Agj9cv):

```java
public static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b(?!\\d*(\\d)\\1)[10]+\\b");
    
public static List<String> findBits(String text) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    return pattern.matcher(text)
        .results()
        .map(MatchResult::group)
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); //.toArray(String[]::new);
}
        
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    List<String> r = findBits("no binary numbers here 3434. Hey friend this is a 1. Those are 1001, 1010, 1011, 1100, 1101. This is a long value 1010101010 and this one as well 1010101010101011. 0 + 0 is a also a 0.");
    System.out.println(r);
}

// => [1, 1010, 1010101010, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to repeat a 1 followed by optional repetitions of 01 and end with an optional zero, or the other way around

```
\b(?>1(?:01)*0?|0(?:10)*1?)\b
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `(?>` Atomic group

  - `1(?:01)*0?` Match `1` optional repetitions of `01` and optional 0
  - `|` Or
  - `0(?:10)*1?` Match `0` optional repetitions of `10` and optional 1
- `)` Close on capture group
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IUCf8i/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/XVmkKl)

For example

```
public static List<String> findBits(String text) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b(?>1(?:01)*0?|0(?:10)*1?)\\b");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    return matcher
        .results().map(MatchResult::group)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Looping the result:

```
for (String item : findBits("no binary numbers here 3434. Hey friend this is a 1. Those are 1001, 1010, 1011, 1100, 1101. This is a long value 1010101010 and this one as well 1010101010101011. 0 + 0 is a also a 0."))
    System.out.println(item);
```

Output

```
1
1010
1010101010
0
0
0
```